# How to "release" intent in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, nfc, android-pendingintent

I have two Activities in my Android app that deal with NFC.  One has a declared `IntentFilter` in the `AndroidManifest.xml`, while the other just accepts NFC actions while it is active using a `PendingIntent` and `onNewIntent();`.  However, sometimes when in the latter activity I actually want to pass the NFC action on the the former.   How do I "release" the Intent to a different activity without losing any of the NFC information within?

Comment: An `Intent` generally just consists of an 'action', (optional) category and data (as extras). Have you tried just extracting the relevant data and adding the action/category that the first `Intent` is registered for and simply broadcasting the new `Intent`?

Comment: I guess that's what I'm asking, how do I broadcast the new intent to nowhere in particular?

Comment: You simply use `startActivity(Intent intent)` but instead of the `Intent` being created using the specific `MyActivity.class` form (an explicit `Intent`), you just add the action/category that the first `Activity` is set to react to in its manifest `<intent-filter>` section (an implicit `Intent`).

Comment: @Squonk please answer the question officially so I can give you the checkmark.

Comment: Converted my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `startActivity(Intent intent)` but instead of the `Intent` being created using the specific `MyActivity.class` form (an explicit Intent), add the action/category that the first `Activity` is set to react to in its manifest `<intent-filter>` section (an implicit Intent).